# In Git, find merged branches which changed same object

Tags: git, merge, git-bash

I have release branch in Git, where many other branches are merged. I would like to find files in release branch, which were merged from more than one branch. I would like also receive names of branches which changed same object.

For example, if `file_x` was changed in `Branch1`, `Branch2` and `Branch3`, and all three branches were merged into `Release` branch, the expected result of the Git command should be:

```
file_x - Branch1 Branch2 Branch3
```

Comment: Files aren't really changed *in a branch*, they're changed *in commits*. The fundamental issue here is that "a branch" is ambiguous in Git: branch *names* are too ephemeral to be used here. You may be able to impose outside (non-Git-enforced) criteria to make this meaningful, but if so, you should outline what those criteria are (e.g., are branches always merged with `--no-ff` and the names always kept?).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all merges were made with `--no-ff`, and each merge commit's comment include the merged branch name, and no branches are deleted.

On release branch, `git log --merges --pretty=format:'%h: %s'` lists merge commits like below:

```
$ git log --merges --pretty=format:'%h: %s'
cca9cf0: Merge branch 'Branch1'
```

In this case, if `git log cca9cf0^..Branch1 file_x` shows any logs file_x was changed in Branch1, otherwise file_x wasn't changed in Branch1.

So, you can write a script that finds all merge commits and the branches by the first `git log` command, checks if the given file is changed using the second `git log` command for each branch, and print the branches which changed the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --first-parent --merges -m --name-only --format=%x0a%H \
| awk '
        NF==0    { tagline=!tagline;next }
        tagline  { commit=$1 }
        !tagline { print commit,$0 }
' \
| sort -k2 | uniq -Df1
```

will get you all files that have been affected by multiple merges to your checked-out branch, and the merges that affected them.